# HttpModule in Child Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, content-management-system

I'm trying to host my site in a child directory of a CMS.

In order to do some initialization, I created an HttpModule and added it to my child virtual directory's web.config....but it doesn't seem to get called....not sure if this is even possible in child virtual directories.

What's the preferred way of hosting my sub-site under the parent CMS and being able to have some initialization code execute?